# Infinispan: How to combine embedded cache and standalone server in one cluster?

Tags: infinispan, jboss-cache

As a proof of concept, I try to build an infinispan cluster with an existing application which starts an embedded cache and one or more standalone infinispan servers.

The reasosing behind this is, that I want to show, that there is a way of zero-configuration automatic creation of a cluster by simply starting freshly downloaded infinispan standalone servers. So my application runs an embedded cache which will be automatically "joined" by new nodes.

I'm using the very default configuration for infinispan and jgroups (see below).

The effect is, that two or more of my applications with embedded cache "see each other" and two or more standalone infinispan servers see each other. But none of my nodes "see" the standalone nodes and they don't see my nodes.

I use infinispan 6.0.2.

The standalone server is this: http://downloads.jboss.org/infinispan/6.0.2.Final/infinispan-server-6.0.2.Final-bin.zip

Please give hints on what to check or links to ressources I could study to make this work.

This is the code, that starts the embedded cache:

```
  DefaultCacheManager manager = new DefaultCacheManager(
    GlobalConfigurationBuilder.defaultClusteredBuilder().transport()
      .nodeName( node ).addProperty( "configurationFile", "jgroups.xml" )
      .build(), new ConfigurationBuilder().clustering()
      .cacheMode( CacheMode.DIST_SYNC ).build() );

  Cache<String, String> cache = manager.getCache( "default" );
```

This is the jgroups-config I'm using:

```
<config xmlns="urn:org:jgroups"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="urn:org:jgroups file:schema/JGroups-3.2.xsd">

    <UDP
            mcast_addr="${jgroups.udp.mcast_addr:228.6.7.8}"
            mcast_port="${jgroups.udp.mcast_port:46655}"
            tos="8"
            ucast_recv_buf_size="200k"
            ucast_send_buf_size="200k"
            mcast_recv_buf_size="200k"
            mcast_send_buf_size="200k"
            loopback="true"
            max_bundle_size="64000"
            max_bundle_timeout="30"
            ip_ttl="${jgroups.udp.ip_ttl:2}"
            enable_bundling="true"
            enable_diagnostics="false"
            bundler_type="old"

            thread_naming_pattern="pl"

            thread_pool.enabled="true"
            thread_pool.min_threads="2"
            thread_pool.max_threads="30"
            thread_pool.keep_alive_time="60000"
            thread_pool.queue_enabled="true"
            thread_pool.queue_max_size="100"
            thread_pool.rejection_policy="Discard"

            oob_thread_pool.enabled="true"
            oob_thread_pool.min_threads="2"
            oob_thread_pool.max_threads="30"
            oob_thread_pool.keep_alive_time="60000"
            oob_thread_pool.queue_enabled="false"
            oob_thread_pool.queue_max_size="100"
            oob_thread_pool.rejection_policy="Discard"
            />

    <PING timeout="3000" num_initial_members="3"/>
    <MERGE2 max_interval="30000" min_interval="10000"/>
    <FD_SOCK/>
    <FD_ALL timeout="15000"/>
    <VERIFY_SUSPECT timeout="5000"/>
    <!-- Commented when upgraded to 3.1.0.Alpha (remove eventually)
    <pbcast.NAKACK  exponential_backoff="0"
                    use_mcast_xmit="true"
                    retransmit_timeout="300,600,1200"
                    discard_delivered_msgs="true"/> -->
    <pbcast.NAKACK2
            xmit_interval="1000"
            xmit_table_num_rows="100"
            xmit_table_msgs_per_row="10000"
            xmit_table_max_compaction_time="10000"
            max_msg_batch_size="100"/>

    <!-- Commented when upgraded to 3.1.0.Alpha (remove eventually)
    <UNICAST timeout="300,600,1200"/>  -->
    <UNICAST2
            stable_interval="5000"
            xmit_interval="500"
            max_bytes="1m"
            xmit_table_num_rows="20"
            xmit_table_msgs_per_row="10000"
            xmit_table_max_compaction_time="10000"
            max_msg_batch_size="100"
            conn_expiry_timeout="0"/>
    <pbcast.STABLE stability_delay="500" desired_avg_gossip="5000" max_bytes="1m"/>
    <pbcast.GMS print_local_addr="false" join_timeout="3000" view_bundling="true"/>
    <UFC max_credits="200k" min_threshold="0.20"/>
    <MFC max_credits="200k" min_threshold="0.20"/>
    <FRAG2 frag_size="8000"  />
    <RSVP timeout="60000" resend_interval="500" ack_on_delivery="true" />
</config>
```

Comment: You should post your server configuration as well. Probably there are differently set JGroups multicasting addresses and ports.
Also, you should enable the compatibility mode http://infinispan.org/docs/6.0.x/user_guide/user_guide.html#_interoperability_between_embedded_and_remote_server_endpoints

Comment: Thank you. I really was underexposed on the whole subject of multicast network adresses. After fixing port and address the only remaining problem was that embedded mode by default worked in IPv6, while the infinispan server preferred IPv4. Now it works, thanks a lot.

Comment: OK, I have added the answer so you can check the question as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is probably in multicast port/address setting in JGroups. Also, check that you use the same IPv4 / IPv6 settings.

Answer (score 1):

Problem Seems with IPv4/IPv6 stack

Use JVM Argument while statring infinispan server

```
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

this will make application to use IPV4 as default stack.